# Persian google search api in PHP

Tags: php, google-search-api

I am using [Google web search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/?hl=en)  in my PHP(laravel) app for search a Persian(farsi) word in web ...

I am using this code for this :

```
<?php

$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=فارسی&userip=192.168.106.1";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://cafesearch.ir/');
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($body);
var_dump($json->responseData);
```

there are not any problems with English , but in Persian I have not any results...

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Where did you write this code in laravel ? This should be in a controller but it doesn't seem like it is.

Comment: now I write this code in a .php file for test in a shared host : http://cafesearch.ir/

Comment: I tried this, and it looks like Google simply says 'there are no results'. What makes you think this is incorrect?

Comment: فارسی means persian and must have resault... I am waiting for you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the Persian bit of your url using php's [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) method.

So basically change your url's definition as the following.

```
$keyword = urlencode('فارسی');    
$url     = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=$keyword&userip=192.168.106.1";
```

using this will give me the following output, which is matching with the result you may get when visiting the [original url](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C&userip=192.168.106.1) in your browser

```
class stdClass#2 (2) {
  public $results =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#3 (8) {
      public $GsearchResultClass =>
      string(10) "GwebSearch"
      public $unescapedUrl =>
      string(46) "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language"
      public $url =>
      string(46) "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language"
      public $visibleUrl =>
      string(16) "en.wikipedia.org"
      public $cacheUrl =>
      string(66) "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:xHz0PgdVXjEJ:en.wikipedia.org"
      public $title =>
      string(51) "Persian language - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"
      public $titleNoFormatting =>
      string(51) "Persian language - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"
      public $content =>
      string(201) "Persian (/ˈpɜrʒən/ or /ˈpɜrʃən/), also known by its endonym <b>Farsi</b> or Parsi (
English: /ˈfɑrsiː/; Persian: <b>فارسی</b> fārsi [fɒːɾˈsiː] ( listen)), is the 
predominant ..."
    }
    [1] =>
    class stdClass#4 (8) {
      public $GsearchResultClass =>
      string(10) "GwebSearch"
      public $unescapedUrl =>
      string(85) "https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86_%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C"
      public $url =>
      string(121) "https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%25D8%25B2%25D8%25A8%25D8%25A7%25D9%2586_%25D9%2581%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B1%25D8%25B3%25DB%258C"
      public $visibleUrl =>
      string(16) "fa.wikipedia.org"
      public $cacheUrl =>
      string(66) "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:Wa73LPvsgnQJ:fa.wikipedia.org"
      public $title =>
      string(78) "زبان <b>فارسی</b> - ویکی‌پدیا، دانشنامهٔ آزاد"
      public $titleNoFormatting =>
      string(71) "زبان فارسی - ویکی‌پدیا، دانشنامهٔ آزاد"
      public $content =>
      string(310) "<b>فارسی</b> یکی از زبان‌های هندواروپایی در شاخهٔ زبان‌های ایرانی جنوب غربی است که در 
کشورهای ایران، افغانستان، تاجیکستان و ازبکستان به آن سخن می‌گویند. <b>فارسی</b> 
زبان ..."
    }
    [2] =>
    class stdClass#5 (8) {
      public $GsearchResultClass =>
      string(10) "GwebSearch"
      public $unescapedUrl =>
      string(70) "http://www.bbc.com/persian/tvandradio/2013/08/000001_bbcpersian_livetv"
      public $url =>
      string(70) "http://www.bbc.com/persian/tvandradio/2013/08/000001_bbcpersian_livetv"
      public $visibleUrl =>
      string(11) "www.bbc.com"
      public $cacheUrl =>
      string(61) "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:HsItkryX0ZAJ:www.bbc.com"
      public $title =>
      string(101) "تلویزیون <b>فارسی</b> بی‌بی‌سی: پخش زنده اینترنتی - BBC Persian"
      public $titleNoFormatting =>
      string(94) "تلویزیون فارسی بی‌بی‌سی: پخش زنده اینترنتی - BBC Persian"
      public $content =>
      string(307) "برنامه های تلویزیون <b>فارسی</b>، هر روز به طور مستقیم و زنده از وبسایت <b>فارسی</b> 
بی‌بی‌سی نیزپخش می شود. با این حال، امکان تماشای بخشی از برنامه‌های تلویزیونی 
به دلیل ..."
    }
    [3] =>
    class stdClass#6 (8) {
      public $GsearchResultClass =>
      string(10) "GwebSearch"
      public $unescapedUrl =>
      string(30) "http://www.farsinet.com/farsi/"
      public $url =>
      string(30) "http://www.farsinet.com/farsi/"
      public $visibleUrl =>
      string(16) "www.farsinet.com"
      public $cacheUrl =>
      string(66) "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:yI1zxZstf_oJ:www.farsinet.com"
      public $title =>
      string(91) "<b>Farsi</b>, the most widely spoken Persian Language, a <b>Farsi</b> Dictionary <b>...</b>"
      public $titleNoFormatting =>
      string(70) "Farsi, the most widely spoken Persian Language, a Farsi Dictionary ..."
      public $content =>
      string(156) "Persian Language, also known as <b>Farsi</b>, is the most widely spoken member of 
the Iranian branch of the Indo-Iranian languages, a subfamily of the ..."
    }
  }
  public $cursor =>
  class stdClass#7 (6) {
    public $resultCount =>
    string(10) "56,600,000"
    public $pages =>
    array(8) {
      [0] =>
      class stdClass#8 (2) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      class stdClass#9 (2) {
        ...
      }
      [2] =>
      class stdClass#10 (2) {
        ...
      }
      [3] =>
      class stdClass#11 (2) {
        ...
      }
      [4] =>
      class stdClass#12 (2) {
        ...
      }
      [5] =>
      class stdClass#13 (2) {
        ...
      }
      [6] =>
      class stdClass#14 (2) {
        ...
      }
      [7] =>
      class stdClass#15 (2) {
        ...
      }
    }
    public $estimatedResultCount =>
    string(8) "56600000"
    public $currentPageIndex =>
    int(0)
    public $moreResultsUrl =>
    string(102) "http://www.google.com/search?oe=utf8&ie=utf8&source=uds&start=0&hl=en&q=%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C"
    public $searchResultTime =>
    string(4) "0.36"
  }
}
```